How to access AppLocalizations inside StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack bottom navigation bar
I'd like to use localised strings in bottom navigation bar using StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack. How to achieve that?
  MaterialApp.router(
    ...
    routerConfig: goRouter
)

final goRouter = GoRouter(
  ...
  routes: [
    StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
      builder: (context, state, navigationShell) {
        return AppFrameWithNavBar(navigationShell: navigationShell);
      },

 class AppFrameWithNavBar extends ConsumerWidget {
  const AppFrameWithNavBar({
    required this.navigationShell,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key ?? const ValueKey('ScaffoldWithNestedNavigation'));
  final StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    _listenForConnectivityChanges(ref, context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: navigationShell,
      bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
        selectedIndex: navigationShell.currentIndex,
        destinations: [
          NavigationDestination(
            label: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.app_name,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.local_drink),
          ),
          NavigationDestination(
            label: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.parties,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.meeting_room),
          ),
          NavigationDestination(
            label: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.user,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.manage_accounts),
          ),
        ],
        onDestinationSelected: _goBranch,
      ),
    );
  }
}

I get a following error: Null check operator used on a null value, problem is Applocalizations.of(context) being null on the app startup.
It seems like a common case - localization of strings in the bottom nav bar. How to achieve that?

I found a solution, turned out I was missing AppLocalizations.delegatein localizationsDelegates list.
 return MaterialApp.router(
      ...
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        AppLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
)

